# Wait for Xcode method to Finish

Tags: ios, avasset, completionhandler

I am using generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes to make some images and save them to a `NSMutableArray`, now when the function `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes` finishes I want to use the image in this array, how can I have the code I want to exectue after all the images have been generated to finish. I would just put it in the `completionHandler` code block, but I don't want it run multiple times I just want to  run it once, after this method has finished.

**EDIT**

This is all inside `- (BFTask *)createImage:(NSInteger)someParameter {`

```
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:passsedAsset];
[imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times
                                     completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,
                                                         AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {
    if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
        NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
        UIImage *saveImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
        [mutaleArray addObject:saveImage];
        //I get Assigment to read only property error on line below
        completionSource.task = saveImage;
    }
]};
```

What should i be assigning that to?

Answer (score 3):

The two approaches I would consider first are NSOperationQueue (you can detect when it's empty) or the easier choice of using the Bolts framework.

Bolts allows you to create an array of tasks that all run asynchronously and then once they're finished it goes on to the next bit.

Let me get a link...

Here you go... https://github.com/BoltsFramework

You can also get this through cocoapods which makes everything much easier.

An example of how bolts works...

At the moment you will have a function that creates an image asynchronously. Something like... `- (UIImage *)createImage: (id)someParameter;` well now you can do this...

```
- (BFTask *)createImage:(NSInteger)someParameter
{
    BFTaskCompletionSource *completionSource = [BFTaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource];

    //create your image asynchronously and then set the result of the task

    someAsyncMethodToCreateYourImageWithACompletionBlock...^(UIImage *createdImage){
        // add the images here...
        [self.imageArray addObject:createdImage];

        // the result doesn't need to be the image it just informs
        // that this one task is complete.
        completionSource.result = createdImage;
    }
    return completionSource.task;
}
```

Now you have to run the tasks in parallel...

```
- (void)createAllTheImagesAsyncAndThenDoSomething
{
    // create the empty image array here
    self.imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSMutableArray *tasks = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i=0 ; i<100 ; ++i) {
        // Start this creation immediately and add its task to the list.
        [tasks addObject:[self createImage:i]];
    }
    // Return a new task that will be marked as completed when all of the created images are finished.
    [[BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
        // this code will only run once all the images are created.
        // in here self.imageArray is populated with all the images.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for post, I wasn't down vote btw, but would you elaborate more about how to use bolts

Comment: Check the GitHub link. I'm on my phone atm so can't do code very well. The section in the read me is called "Tasks in Parallel". It will show you how to create an array of tasks and then have a single completion handler once that entire array has finished processing.

Comment: Could the down voter please leave a comment to explain why my answer is incorrect? Or are they just being cowardly?

Comment: Great, this looks awesome I will give it a try, one last thing is I am a bit confused on how to add it to my Xcode project, the installation instructions aren't clear, could you tell me?

Comment: @iqueqiorio go to http://cocoapods.org and have a look at installing that. It is much much easier and once you have it working you can use it for all projects in the future. The bolts framework is available through cocoa pods too.

Comment: I think I installed it what do I import  to use Bolts?

Comment: Have a read of the cocoapods instructions. Once you understand it you just search for "bolts" framework and click the clipboard button to copy the text for you Podfile. Using frameworks can be complicated the first time so take your time to ready the cocoapods stuff and learn it so you know for next time.

Comment: Also, there are tons of SO questions about using cocoapods.

Comment: Great I got it, the last thing I added an edit to the question if you would mind taking a look, Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Your task method should only create one image at a time. So each BFTask creates a single image. You then create multiple tasks. So that when they have all finished running then you will have multiple images. Split out your code for creating a single image.

Comment: Also, don't copy and paste my method name. It was just an example, you need to use a method name that is relevant to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75073/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-fogmeister).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:completionHandler:` calls its completion handlers sequentially (that seems reasonable, but the docs don't explicitly promise), then this is very simple. Just set a `__block` variable to the count of your `times` and decrement it once per completion. When it's zero, call your other function.

```
__block NSInteger count = [times count];
    [imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times
                                     completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,
                                                         AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {

        ... Do all the stuff ...
        if (--count <= 0) {
            finalize()
        }
```

If `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:` actually does work in parallel and so might call the completion handlers in parallel, then you can handle all of this with dispatch groups.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

//
// Enter the group once for each time
//
[times enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
}];

//
// This local variable will be captured, so you don't need a property for it.
//
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];

//
// Register a block to fire when it's all done
//
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Whatever you want to do when everything is done.");
    NSLog(@"results is captured by this: %@", results);
});

AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:nil];
[imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times
                                     completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,
                                                         AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
         //
         // Create saveImage
         //
         id saveImage = @"";

         //
         // Update external things on a serial queue.
         // You may use your own serial queue if you like.
         //
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [results addObject:saveImage];
         });

         //
         // Signal we're done
         //
         dispatch_group_leave(group);
     }
 }];
```